# How to display shortcode of specific function on Ultimate Member tab plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have add this code to my functions.php for displaying Woocommerce Recent Orders:

```
//display recent orders
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

Now how to display that "Woocommerce Recent Orders" of [woocommerce_orders] function on Ultimate Member tab?

I'll appreciate for your answers. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Use this on your plugin template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); ?>
```

Comment: i don't know why, that code make the display like this: http://prntscr.com/kvlu2c

Comment: @CuanqGigabyte try to use only this: `[woocommerce_my_account]`

Answer (score 0):

you can render the shortcode using echo do_shortcode, and later with jQuery/JS append the HTML into the div you need to show the content.

Another way to do it is to edit directly the plugin's files. 
/ultimate-member/templates/profile.php you can find the template file.just add your function there and it will render.

Also you can add a filter on your theme's function.php to override the plugin.

If you modify the plugin be sure to *null* it by changing the version and name of the plugin to 99.99.99 -to avoid automatic updates to override your changes.